# SpringSource Tool Suite Change Themes

Tags: eclipse, grails, themes, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

When I became aware of [Sublime](http://www.sublimetext.com/), I noticed the benefits of dark themes to your workspace. But since Sublime doesn't have support for Grails at the moment, I search for ways to theme STS or SpringSource Tool Suite and I reached to this [article](http://zoltanb.co.uk/how-to-change-the-colour-theme-in-eclipse-distros/). I tried the plugin and it worked well. Unfortunately, only the Editor area was change by the plugin.

The question is how I change the `Color and Fonts` of the whole STS or Eclipse?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use the current STS milestone (STS 3.0.0), then it is possible, because the underlying Eclipse 4 is now completely themeable. There are already some themes available, however you should consider them beta.

Here is a place to pick a color theme for your editing window:
http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to change the color/theme of the non-editing windows within STS or Eclipse.  Are you able to change the background color of the "Package Explorer" or "Console" views?

Comment: I have these two installed. Yes it changes the background color of Package Explorer.

http://guari.github.io/eclipse-ui-theme/
https://github.com/jeeeyul/eclipse-themes

Comment: The article mentioned in the question throws 404.

Answer (score 23):

Go to Windows->Preferences->General->Appearance->Select the theme you want.

Answer (score 13):

download the plugin here : http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=plugin

If you are on Eclipse 3.6 (Helios), the easiest way to install the plugin is from the Eclipse Marketplace. Go to Help→Eclipse Marketplace..., then search for Eclipse Color Theme and install it.

If you are on Eclipse 3.5 (Galileo), go to Help→Install New Software..., press Add Site and enter Eclipse Color Theme as the name and http://eclipse-color-theme.github.com/update as the URL. Then select the new entry from the select box labeled Work with, mark Eclipse Color Theme for installation and proceed.

Please note: If you are using a version of the plugin lower than 0.6, please uninstall and reinstall it following the instructions above. Update site and plugin ID have changed.

Usage

After the installation, go to Window→Preferences→General→Appereance→Color Theme to change the color theme.

Comment: I like this answer more than "accepted" one as this actually details **how** to get the themes onto your STS

Answer (score 10):

**1. Changing theme of Spring Tool Suite without downloading any plugin.**
(For using Darkest Dark Theme see option 2)

First, go to

`Window` > `Preferences`

[image]

Then in **Preferences** dialog go to

`General` > `Appearance`

after that select **Dark* in the dropdown for **Theme**, after that click on **Apply**, then on **Apply and Close**

[image]

Then restart **STS** once so your **STS** will look like this

[image]

**2. Changing theme of Spring Tool Suite by downloading Darkest Dark plugin.**

First go to

`Help` > `Eclipse Marketplace...`

[image]

Then in **Eclipse Marketplace** dialog search for **Darkest Dark** and then click on **Go**.

After that from the search results install the plugin named **Darkest Dark Theme with DevStyle**

[image]

After that with default options selected click on **Confirm**

[image]

Then accept the license and click on **Finish**

[image]

Then let the software install

[image]

After installation completes click on **Restart** in the pop up

[image]

Then in the welcome screen click on **Next**

[image]

After that select **Darkest Dark Theme** and click on **Next**

[image]

Then let the **STS** launch with **Darkest Dark Theme**

[image]

Then click on **Continue** in the **Tweak the Workbench** dialog

[image]

Then your **STS** will look like this

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can go to Marketplace Eclipse and search for Darkest Dark Theme. As the name says a pretty cool dark theme.